# NHibernate subclass with join table with bag of subclass problem

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Hi guys
I have a model of that type

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
}

class EntityA : BaseEntity
{
    ..other properties..
    IList<EntityB> BEntities {get; set;}
}

class EntityB : BaseEntity
{
    ..other properties..
    EntityA Owner {get, set;}
}
```

mapped as follow:

```
  <class name="BaseEntity" abstract="true" table="TBL_BaseEntity"
         dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id"
        column="ID_ENTiTY"
        type="guid"
        unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>

    <discriminator column="EtityType" type="string" force="true" />
  </class>

<subclass name="EntityA"
            extends="BaseEntity"
            discriminator-value="A"
            dynamic-insert="true"
            dynamic-update="true"
            lazy="true">

    <join table="TBL_ENTITYA">
      <key column="ID_ENTITYA" />

      ...other mapped properties...

      <bag name="BEntities" cascade="save-update"
           lazy="true" inverse="true" fetch="select" outer-join="true" >
        <key column="ID_ENTITYA" />
        <one-to-many class="EntityB"/>
      </bag>
    </join>
  </subclass>

<subclass name="EntityB"
            extends="BaseEntity"
            discriminator-value="B"
            dynamic-insert="true"
            dynamic-update="true"
            lazy="true">

    <join table="TBL_ENTITYB">
      <key column="ID_ENTITYB" />

      ...other mapped properties...

      <many-to-one name="Owner" not-null="true"
                   lazy="proxy" fetch="select" column="ID_ENTITYA" />
    </join>
  </subclass>
```

now the issue is when I try to insert and cascade a new EntityA with a collection of EntityB correctly initialized (in terms of the bidirectional association) everything works,
but when I try to read the EntityA.BEntities collection I got an exception which states that NH could execute the query.
After whatching the  issue with NHProf I saw that the query produced is incorrect because NH append the column ID_ENTITYA to base table (which clearly not has that column) and not to the
destination joined subclass table.
Anyone can help me about this prblem?
How can I avoid that behavior?
It's possible to do that in NH?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon no I have not, because I don't know if joined-subclass make the same feature.. a derived entity spawned between two tables.. I have to try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We've just run into the same problem here, and I colleague of mine found this solution:

Create a many-to-one bi-directional relationship on EntityB back to EntityA.

This seems to help NH to figure out that the FK relationship exists between EntityA & EntityB, instead of BaseEntity & EntityB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to try it.. after I will tell you if this is a possible solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently and submitted an issue for this:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2564

Comment: as one answered me in NHUsers user group, this is an issue with low priority.. so if no one else asks to resolve that bug wouldn't be. If you try to do that thing with joined-subclass instead everything works!....